cannot import name 'awscrt' from 'botocore.compat
I have a lambda that needs to:

prepare payload
sign request with AWS ver 4
send request to another service and return response

While I'm running lambda I get this message:
cannot import name 'awscrt' from 'botocore.compat' (/opt/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botocore/compat.py

Apparently, awscrt is missing, I created a layer that has this dependency but still the problem persists.
NOTE: I followed this logic: sigv4-authenticated-requests-python

Can you share some code for your lambda layer creation? What architecture (x86, x64, arm) and OS are you using to build the lambda layer?

If it works locally and not working within lambda environment, it could be happening due to platform incompatibility of platform-specific _awscrt.abi3.so (botocore.compat hiding the real exception message):
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'lambda_function': /var/task/_awscrt.abi3.so: invalid ELF header

The solution would be to either build lambda package with the using Docker with explicit platform specification:
# assuming there is a valid Dockerfile that builds and packages what you need
docker build --platform linux/x86_64 -t lambda-layer 


Another solution would be to not to use awscrt library and use SigV4Auth instead of CrtSigV4Auth
import boto3
import requests
from botocore.auth import SigV4Auth
from requests import PreparedRequest
from requests.auth import AuthBase

from botocore.awsrequest import AWSRequest

class BotoSigV4Auth(AuthBase):
    def __init__(self, service, session=None):
        self.service = service
        self.session = session or boto3.session.Session()
        self.sign_required_headers = ["content-type", "host", "x-amz-date", "x-amz-security-token"]

    def __call__(self, r: PreparedRequest):
        aws_signer = SigV4Auth(self.session.get_credentials(), self.service, self.session.region_name)
        aws_headers = {
            k: v for k, v in r.headers.items() if k.lower() in self.sign_required_headers
        }
        aws_request = AWSRequest(method=r.method, url=r.url, headers=aws_headers, data=r.body)
        aws_signer.add_auth(aws_request)
        aws_prepared = aws_request.prepare()
        r.url = aws_prepared.url
        r.headers.update(aws_prepared.headers)
        return r

auth = BotoSigV4Auth("healthlake")

response = requests.get(
   auth=auth, 
   # other params
)


